# Custom Weighted Cross Entropy loss in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, loss-function

Ok, so I have a neural network that classifies fire size into 3 groups, 0-1, 1 - 100, and over 100 acres.  I need a loss function that weights the loss as double when the classifier guesses a class that is off by 2 (Actual = 0, predicted = 3)

Answer (score 0):

`I need a loss function that weights the loss as double when the classifier guesses a class that is off by 2 (Actual = 0, predicted = 3)`

double of what?.

A)Is it the double the loss value when the classifier guesses correctly,

B)or double the loss value when the classifier is off by 1.

C)Can we relax this 'double' constraint, and can we assume that any suitable higher power would suffice?

Let us assume A).

Let f(x) denotes the probability that your input variable belong to a particular class. Note that, in f(x), x is the absolute value of the  difference in categorical value.

Then we see that f(0)=0.5 is a solution for assumption A. This means that f(1)=0.25 and f(2)=0.25. Btw, the fact that f(1)==f(2) doesn't look natural.

Assume that your classifier calculates a function f(x), and uses it as follows.

```
def classifier_output(firesize):
    if (firesize >=0 and firesize < 1.0):
        return [f(0), f(1), f(2)]
    elif  (firesize >= 1.0 and firesize < 100.0):
        return [f(1), f(0), f(1)]
    else :
        assert(firesize > 100.0)
        return (f(2), f(1), f(0)]
```

The constraints are

C1)

```
f(x) >=0
```

C2)

```
the components of your output vector should always sum to 1.0
ie. sum of all three components of the return value should always be 1.
```

C3)

```
When the true class and predicted class differ by 2, the 1-hot encoding loss 
will be -log(f(2)), According to assumption A, this should equal -2log(f(0)).
```

ie:

```
log(f(2))=2*log(f(0))
```

This translates to

```
f(2) = f(0)*f(0)
```

Let us put  z=f(0). Now f(2)=z*z. We don't know f(1). Let us assume, f(1)=y.

From the constraint C2,
We have the following equations,

```
z+ z*z + y=1
z + 2*y=1
```

A solution to the above is z=0.5, y=0.25

If you assume B), you wont be able to find such a function.